# Phone, a phone, or the phone

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article

Which option is correct and why? I want to talk about smartphones in general.

> Phone is a distraction.
>
> A phone is a distraction.
>
> The phone is a distraction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greybeard says you should always use an article in this type of sentence, at least if the noun is singular (it is possible to say things like "Phones are a distraction"). However when using singular nouns the indefinite article 'a' and the definite article 'the' give different meanings to the sentence.

"*A* phone is a distraction" implies that any specific phone you use is distracting whereas "*The* phone is a distraction" usually implies that phones in general are distracting.

At first sight this seems wrong because, normally, the definite article is more specific that the indefinite article (consider "Pass me a phone" and "Pass me the phone") but the reason for this particular usage is that 'The phone' used like this usually refers to the *concept* of the phone rather than any specific piece of hardware.

The only case where this is not true is where a specific phone is identified by the context, for example "When I'm working from home the phone is a distraction" identifies either their specific mobile phone or, if not the specific handset in the speaker's home office, the landline connection to the house regardless of the number of handsets.

Comment: Or when the singular noun is a mass noun: *Bread **is** a distraction*. That's singular, but it's fine. However, *phone* is not a mass noun, so it can't be used without an article—unless it's used as an adjective: *Phone use **is** a distraction*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This explanation is extremely helpful!

Comment: @Jason Bassford 'Bread' is singular in form in _Bread is available on aisle 14_, not a singular noun. It's a mass / non-count _usage_ here. 'Bread' is occasionally used in count fashion, the singular form being 'bread' and the plural form being 'breads'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Mass nouns are strange. They are neither strictly singular nor plural. As amorphous entities, which can describe a single thing or multiple things, they exist in an undefined state. Especially as a concept, they are singular—even if they could describe multiple units of something. Or just one unit. Assuming the use of units is even appropriate. Any kind of proper discussion of this goes far beyond these kind of comments. Nothing I said in my original comment contradicts this.

Comment: 'Or when the singular noun is a mass noun' is certainly at best in contravention of a Gricean maxim. It is far better to speak of _count_ and _non-count_ **usages**, since many, many nouns exhibit both. And countification, and at a slower pace massification, is quite productive. This corresponds to not labelling say 'smoke' a 'transitive verb'.

Answer (score 0):

> Phone is a distraction.

This is incorrect: as general guidance, all singular, countable nouns require a determiner. "Phone" is a singular countable noun.

> A phone is a distraction.
>
> The phone is a distraction.

Because of the above guidance, both of these are correct.

> I want to talk about smartphones in general.

Then you should not use "phone" as that includes all phones of every type and age.